# Magento - product edit page is not working after being upgraded to 1.9.3.7

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

after upgrading my site to 1.9.3.7, I want to edit the product, but it seems that the blocks are not loaded successfully.
Please see the image:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymLQE.png)
Please help.

Comment: add recent entries from ../var/log/system.log and try to clean caches

Comment: Have you check system.log file? Also check consol?

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing all your caches including JS/CSS after you update versions. Your screenshot appears to be missing CSS files. If the problem persists, try recompiling.